# Can I use subliminals to get taller? Is it permissible? I just want to get a little bit taller

Tags: halal-haram

I don't want to change anything in my appearance, I just want to get a little bit taller through programing my sub-conscious mind, I've heard that our subconscious mind has a unique power to break the barriers for our desires....I just want to get a little bit taller through subliminals, because I feel very insecured about my height....is this permissible in Islam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is haram to use subliminals as you are attempting to change your appearance. Allah has made every human unique so why change what you have. Be blessed with what Allah has provided you. I am also a bit self conscious about my height but I try not to think about it as Allah has blessed me with everything I have. Trying to change your appearance is also a sin as you are trying to change what Allah has created.

Set steady to the fitrah created by Allah for us: (Ar-Ruum 30:30)

“So set thou thy face steadily and truly to the Faith: (establish) Allah.s handiwork according to the pattern on which He has made mankind: no change (let there be) in the work (wrought) by Allah. that is the standard Religion: but most among mankind understand not.”

Comment: I also have unwanted body hair which is way too excessive...My doctor has said that I have hormonal imbalance and having excess skin hair is one of it's symptoms, I also have a disease because of this hormonal imbalance, this whole thing is a disease, and I am very insecured about my body hair, so I don't think it is a part of my appearance, since it comes from a disease and can be cured in no time, but I don't have enough money for that, so can I try out subliminals in this case?

Comment: @Usman I don't think attempting to change appearance is haram? By that logic skinny people cannot work out because it's attempting to change appearance (It's not haram). By that logic eating Nutritious food in order to get taller is also haram (it's not haram). i think it's only haram to change appearance through surgery, tattoos etc. Subliminal is purely to give a placebo effect and therefore not haram.  Unless you believe in LOA then it's shirk

Comment: Working out is completely different in terms of you work naturally to increase muscle growth through  working out and eating. There are many sources which state that the use of subliminals aren’t allowed.